# Android Studio SQLite database. unknown error

Tags: android, sqlite

I am getting an error with the method below.

I would like to do a `SELECT WHERE` statement.

My goal is to know, if the variable name is already in my database.

The error seems to occur at `statement.execute();` It is :-

> ```
> "Caused By : unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only. "
> ```

The program has worked properly many times before but now it does not.

The method is :-

```
public int count(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM myBD WHERE NAME1 = ?";
    SQLiteStatement statement = database.compileStatement(countQuery);
    statement.clearBindings();
    statement.bindString(1, name);
    statement.execute();
    //database.close();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();enter code here
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the query convenience method e.g. :-

```
public int count(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase database = getWritableDatabase();
    String whereclause = "NAME1=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{name};
    Cursor cursor = database.query("myBD",null,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    database.close();
    return count;
}
```

- **Note** the above is in-principle code, it hasn't been checked or run and may therefore contain some errors.

Unknown errors are often related to subsequent lines following a **;** the convenience methods enclose arguments and build the SQL on your behalf.

Comment: Thank you so much Mike T for your quick answer.

Comment: @Kel np, if it fixes the issue please remember to tick the answer to say that it answered the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use 
database.rawQuery("Your query here");

Comment: The **rawQuery** method does not have a constructor with a single parameter [rawQuery](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)) so that answer wouldn't work as it stands. `database.rawQuery("Your query here",null);` may but there could be issues and also susceptibility to sql-injection. Rather `database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myBD WHERE NAME1 = ?",new String[]{name});` would be the correct/proper way.